# Ruby code for Choice build parameter within Jenkins job (configured via Chef)

Tags: ruby, jenkins, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I need to make a drop down / Choice selection for one of my automated builds.

Here's the finished XML that I can observe when I configure the job on-the-fly from the front end (I need to translate this into the Chef recipe that I am creating):

```
<property>
<parameterDefinition>
<defaultParameterValue>
<name>DATA_BAG_NAME</name>
<value>X</value>
</defaultParameterValue>
<description>Select the data bag that contains the job above.</description>
<name>DATA_BAG_NAME</name>
<type>ChoiceParameterDefinition</type>
<choice>X</choice>
<choice>Y</choice>
<choice>Z</choice>
</parameterDefinition>
</property>
```

I have also attached a screenshot of what the manual configuration looks like. [image]

Finally,

Here is the *non* working code I have written up for my Chef Recipe:

```
:build_params => [
  { 'name' => 'JENKINS_ID_TO_ADD', 'type' => 'String', 'default' => '', 
    'description' => ' Enter the JenkinsID you want to add, example: PRCalculator' },
  { 'name' => 'DATA_BAG_NAME', 'type' => 'Choice', 'choices' => 
    'description' => ' Select the data bag that contains the job above.' }

],
```

Please help me determine what type of Ruby Syntax I need to make the drop down list actually contain values, instead of "'choices' => " which is what I have right now. Any permutation I try results in failure to configure, or success with 0 elements in the dropdown.

~EDIT: Adding in further code to help troubleshoot:

```
config_name = 'free-style'
job_name = "flag-chef-add-jenkins-id"

job_config = File.join(Chef::Config[:file_cache_path], "#{job_name}-config.xml")

template job_config do
  source File.join('jenkins',"job-#{config_name}-config.xml.erb")
  variables :job_name => job_name,
    :max_builds => '15',
    :build_params => [
      { 'name' => 'JENKINS_ID_TO_ADD', 'type' => 'String', 'default' => '', 
        'description' => ' Enter the JenkinsID you want to add, example: MyJobID' },
      { 'name' => 'DATA_BAG_NAME', 'type' => 'Choice', 'choice' => '1', 'choice' => '2',
        'description' => ' Select the data bag that contains the job above.' }

    ],
    :command => "
if [ \"$JENKINS_ID_TO_ADD\" != \"\" ]; then
  # run gimmicky update that wont work!
  echo \"Jenkins ID to add or update: \" 
  echo \"Running Jenkins_ID_To_Add job for the following ID: $JENKINS_ID_TO_ADD .'\n\" >> jenkinsIDTest.txt
  echo recipe['jenkins::master'],recipe[\"flag_utils::data_bags::promo_lps::$JENKINS_ID_TO_ADD\"] >> jenkinsIDTest.txt
  sudo -u root -i chef-client -o recipe['jenkins::master'],recipe[\"flag_utils::data_bags::promo_lps::$JENKINS_ID_TO_ADD\"] --force-formatter >> jenkinsIDTest.txt

fi
    ",
    :email_release_subject => 'Flag Utils Chef add Jenkins ID run! $JENKINS_ID_TO_ADD',
    :admin_emails => admin_emails,
    :notification_emails => notification_emails
end

jenkins_job job_name do
  config job_config
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Chef you can generate the jobs's *config.xml* file using a chef [template resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_template.html).

Better still I recommend using the [Jenkins cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/jenkins) which has a **jenkins_job** resource that takes a template as a parameter.

## Update - Cookbook example

I have created the following "demo" cookbook to illustrate how to install Jenkins and configure a parametrized job.

```
├── Berksfile
├── metadata.rb
├── recipes
│   └── default.rb
├── templates
│   └── default
│       └── choice-job.xml.erb
└── attributes
    ├── java.rb
    └── jenkins.rb
```

### recipes/default.rb

```
#
# Cookbook Name:: demo
# Recipe:: default
#
# Copyright (c) 2016 The Authors, All Rights Reserved.
#
include_recipe "apt"
include_recipe "java"
include_recipe "jenkins::master"

#
# Jenkins job
#
jobxml = File.join(Chef::Config[:file_cache_path], 'choice-job.xml')

template jobxml do
  source "choice-job.xml.erb"
  variables :choices => ["X", "Y", "Z"]
end

jenkins_job "Choice Demo" do
  config jobxml
end
```

Note:

- An xml file is generated by the template and passed to the Jenkins job resource.
- Passing in 3 parameters that will appear as choices in the Jenkins UI

### templates/default/choice-job.xml.erb

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project>
  <actions/>
  <description>Demo job</description>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties>
    <hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty>
      <parameterDefinitions>
        <hudson.model.ChoiceParameterDefinition>
          <name>DATA_BAG_NAME</name>
          <description></description>
          <choices class="java.util.Arrays$ArrayList">
            <a class="string-array">
              <% @choices.each do |choice| -%>
              <string><%= choice %></string>
              <% end -%>
            </a>
          </choices>
        </hudson.model.ChoiceParameterDefinition>
      </parameterDefinitions>
    </hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty>
  </properties>
  <scm class="hudson.scm.NullSCM"/>
  <canRoam>true</canRoam>
  <disabled>false</disabled>
  <blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
  <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
  <triggers/>
  <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
  <builders>
    <hudson.tasks.Shell>
      <command>env</command>
    </hudson.tasks.Shell>
  </builders>
  <publishers/>
  <buildWrappers/>
</project>
```

Note the following fragment:

```
<% @choices.each do |choice| -%>
<string><%= choice %></string>
<% end -%>
```

The "choices" are passed into the template

### metadata.rb

```
name 'demo'
maintainer 'The Authors'
maintainer_email 'you@example.com'
license 'all_rights'
description 'Installs/Configures demo'
long_description 'Installs/Configures demo'
version '0.1.0'

depends "apt"
depends "java"
depends "jenkins"
```

### Berksfile

```
source 'https://supermarket.chef.io'

metadata
```

Note:

- Dependencies pulled from supermarket by Berkshelf

### attributes/java.rb

```
normal['java']['jdk_version'] = '7'
```

Note:

- Jenkins needs at least Java7

### attributes/jenkins.rb

```
normal['jenkins']['master']['install_method'] = "war"
normal['jenkins']['master']['version']  = "1.655"
normal['jenkins']['master']['checksum'] = "0cee889af697c115961ce50229cc5e39d1b798c0a0a689687b745c0a938c8547"
```

Note:

- Specifying the version and checksum avoids the need to check for the latest version

Comment: Mark, I absolutely have all of this as underlying infrastructure already established. This build parameter that I am trying to generate (Choice, rather than String) is just tough for me to figure out in Ruby. I can't quite get it right. Do you perhaps know where I can find examples using the jenkins cookbook? Specific job configurations, that is.

Comment: You are attempting to control the options displayed in the Jenkins build job, correct? In that case you need to generate an XML file. Template resources are used in Chef to do this. The build parameters can be passed as variables or alternatively accessed as node attributes.

Comment: To be clearer: this isn't a Ruby question, or a general Chef question. Look at how your template builds the XML and make the data work with that. That could be anything as we don't know what cookbook(s) you are using.

Comment: Mark, I added the full recipe for this particular build job that will flesh out the template. Again, I'm having trouble adding the Dynamic Build Parameter of type "Choice" or "Dynamic Choice" - in the edited-in code I've included in the original question you can see "DATA_BAG_NAME" - that's the parameter that I am trying to add properly. I want to ensure the Choice parameter has a dropdown of a few selection choices. With the code as written, there are no choices in the dropdown, but the dropdown appears.

Comment: @Davek804 You haven't provided the template file you're using. To save time I have supplied a working example that passes in 3 parameters that appear as choices in the Jenkins UI.

Answer (score 0):

```
xml = File.join(Chef::Config[:file_cache_path], 'rconfig.xml')

template xml do
  source 'jconfig.xml.erb'
end

jenkins_job 'project' do
 config xml
action :create
end
```

This is the code example. This might help. "jconfig.xml" is my config.xml file for jenkins job